# how to handle OverflowException in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I need to handle OverflowException in method mul().

```
class B
{
    short a, b;
    public B(short a, short b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }
    public short mul()
    {
        try
        {
            return checked((short)(a * b));
        }
        catch (OverflowException exc) { Console.WriteLine(exc); }
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B m1 = new B(1000, 500);
        m1.mul();
    }
}
```

But the above code gives the following error :Error CS0161: 'B.mul()': not all code paths return a value (CS0161)

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Return a value after catching the exception

Comment: That means that there's a case where `mul()` doesn't `return` a value. It's easy to find, if think about what your code does.

Comment: All answers mention adding a 2nd `return`, within the `catch` - you can also have a single `return`, outsite the try/catch block (usually what I do)

Comment: `return short.MinValue` after the `try...catch` or make the return type a `short?` and return `null`(to avoid the problem that `short.MinValue` could be a valid multiplication result).

Comment: Your exception is handled, but your function does not return anything if the `OverflowException` happens.

Answer (score 5):

Please, do *not mix* logic and UI; just put `try {} catch {}` to its proper place and everything will be clear:

```
class B 
{
    ...

    // Logic: multiply with possible Overflow exception
    // Let us be nice and document the exception 
    ///<exception cref="System.OverflowException">
    ///When a or (and) b are too large
    ///</exception> 
    public short mul()
    {
        // Do we know how to process the exception at the place? 
        // No. There're many reasonable responses: 
        // - stop execution
        // - use some special/default value (e.g. -1, short.MaxValue)   
        // - switch to class C which operates with int (or BigInteger) etc.
        // That's why we don't catch exception here  
        return checked((short)(a * b));
    }
}
```

...

```
class MainClass
{
    // UI: perform operation and show the result on the console
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B m1 = new B(1000, 500);

        try 
        { 
            m1.mul();
        }
        catch (OverflowException exc) 
        { 
            // Proper place to catch the exception: only here, at UI, 
            // we know what to do with the exception:
            // we should print out the exception on the Console
            Console.WriteLine(exc); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When exception is thrown you write something to console but don't return any value.

Your method return value is `short` so you should return some value in `catch` (because method should return some `short` value in every execution path or throw):

```
try 
{
    return checked((short)(a * b)); 
}

catch(OverflowException exc) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(exc);

    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mul()` does not return a value when an exception is caught. Add a `return` statement to the `catch` block or at the end of the method:

```
public short mul()
{
    try {
        return checked((short)(a * b)); }
    catch(OverflowException exc) {
        Console.WriteLine(exc);
        return 0; // or whatever
    }
    return 0; // this goes as well
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to throw exception from catch block. For example:

```
catch(OverflowException exc) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(exc)
    throw exc;
}
```

Comment: this will resolve OP compilation problem, but still is not a good advice. It introduce the need to check for a special value. Moreover negative numbers are possibly allowed.